# Integrating Flask Security and Flask Rest-JSONAPI

Tags: flask

i try to build a REST API with Flask-JSONAPI and Flask Security.
I use Auth Token for authentication and `@login_required` to secure my API Endpints. (Authentication)
But now I want to ensure that only the owner of objects (Creator) can (C)RUD the data. Right now every user can see every object that is created. (Autorisation)

I want to use [Resource Manager](https://flask-rest-jsonapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resource_manager.html) here but did't find a proper example for Flask Security in Resource Managers.
For [Example](https://github.com/miLibris/flask-rest-jsonapi/blob/master/examples/api.py) the user (person) can only see the computer objects associated with the same user id. 
Do I have to use the Auth Token for that? 
Is there a simple way to get the id of the user logged in, doing the request?

Answer (score 1):

```
from flask_security import current user
```

That represents a user instance of the currently logged in user. This user can be anonymous in cases where no user is logged in, but if a user is logged in then the object will represent an object of the User class.